# How to continue drawing from the last point(LineString) in openlayers 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers-3

What I need to do is to start drawing from the last point of our LineString **after calling finishDrawing method.**
so I have this code

```
  var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
  var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ source: vectorSource });
  var drawLine = new ol.interaction.Draw({
     source: vectorSource,
     type: 'LineString'
  });
  map.addLayer(vectorLayer);


  if(triggered)
      drawLine.finishDrawing();
```

and then in another statement we should **continue drawing from the last LineString point**

```
if(!triggered)//for example
    //please add your solution how to continue drawing from the last point
```

Comment: Is this some kind of assignment?

Comment: @mistapink I think this is some kind of adding function(-s)

Comment: @mistapink another solution can be just by hiding the last line which is moving with our mouse. Do you know how to do it?